# phpgrid using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gridview

I'm working on a web application using [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com) and i want to use [php grid](http://phpgrid.com/)
 in displaying information but i dont know how to do it with codeigniter! Is there anyone has worked with php grid using codeignitier? Help please!! I'm would have opted for [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/)
but it doesn't offer so much functionality such as exporting to various document format(excel, word, e.t.c).
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with php grid, but usually you can just throw a class file in `application/libraries` and then load it like this:

```
$this->load->library('phpgrid');
// and use it like this
$this->phpgrid->phpgrid_method();
```

Comment: thanx.. that helps! BTW do you know how and when to use the third_party folder found in application folder of the current versions?

Comment: Yeah, they're for packages (which are new to CI2) -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248158/codeigniter-2-0-third-party-folder

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to load [php datagrid](http://phpgrid.com) or any 3rd party PHP libraries.

```
$this->load->library('phpgrid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/) is to directly include third party libraries without calling load library.

```
require_once(APPPATH. 'libraries/phpGrid_Lite/conf.php'); 
$data['phpgrid'] = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM Orders", "orderNumber", "Orders"); //$this->ci_phpgrid->example_method(3);
```

APPPATH is explained in this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337411/how-do-i-include-external-libraries-in-codeigniter).

[image]