# Referencing other scripts from within my controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to Code Igniter. I want to use some 3rd party classes in my application. The first of which is a class that helps with interacitng with the POstmark email service.

I tried to put the class in libraries and call it like so from my controller:

```
 require("../libraries/postmark.php");
```

But this caused a no such file or directory error. Where is the best place to put these sorts of files and how do I reference them in my controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337411/how-do-i-include-external-libraries-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are pretty clear about these things

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

You basically put your class in the library directory and then create an instance...

```
$this->load->library('postmark');
```

You can then call your postmark functions using the syntax:

```
$this->postmark->function1();
$this->postmark->function2();
```

While this may not be the most complete example, there is no reason for me to rewrite the docs I just linked to. Hope it helps.