# how to require_once in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, require

I am trying to extend a library in codeigniter. The only way to do so seems to include the original library using `require_once` then load the extended library using `$this->load->library()`

right now I have tried

1. `require_once('ion_auth.php');`
2. `require_once('home/SITE_NAME/public_html/FOLDER_NAME/application/libraries/ion_auth.php')`
3. `require_once('/home/SITE_NAME/public_html/FOLDER_NAME/application/libraries/ion_auth.php')`

but unfortunately not luck..... I keep getting this error

```
Message: require_once(...) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Weird thing is though this works on my local xampp environment but not on the actual server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include external Libraries in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337411/how-do-i-include-external-libraries-in-codeigniter)

Comment: tried it.not working unfortunately

Answer (score 33):

Use CodeIgniter's built in constant, `APPPATH`

`require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/ion_auth.php');`

Comment: still an error. require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'application/libraries/ion_auth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/SITE_NAME/public_html/FOLDER_NAME/application/libraries/auth.php

Comment: In that case, we have 2 possibilities: 1) the path is incorrect, 2) the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9):

If the library is a codeigniter specific library, as sbaaaang points out, you should use:

```
$this->load->library('ion_auth');
```

However, if the library is just a generic PHP class or set of functions, the codeiginter loader may not recognize it.  Then you will need to use either one of the generic loading operators (include, include_once, require, require_once), with the APPPATH constant, as also pointed out:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/ion_auth.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that Codeigniter has a [loader class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html)?

change this

```
require_once('/home/SITE_NAME/public_html/FOLDER_NAME/application/libraries/ion_auth.php')
```

to

```
$this->load->library('ion_auth');

and be sure your libraries/ion_auth.php file it's a class named `class ion_auth{}`
```

Comment: thats how I have temporarily solved the problem. However using the loader class of codeigniter 'loads' the library (instantiates an object), and I dont want to 'load' the ion_auth library since I am extending it. hence, I only want to load the extended library.

Comment: @death_relic0 do you now how to load an extended lib? just call that My_ion_auth.php or better look at the Codeigniter Documentation, how to create own libraries, is so simple ... :P