# Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007' not found in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I am beginner person in codeigniter.

I have face one error in PHPExcel. can anyone tell me how to fixed it.?

Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007' not found in PHPExcel IOFactory.php on line 171

Thanks

Comment: You may be more likely to get help if you tag this question `codeigniter` as well

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977805/how-to-require-once-in-codeigniter/17977950#17977950